# Setting max_Retrieve and sort_list parameter in getListEntryObjects

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am new to AR System Java API.

I was going through the code the below code:

```
String formName = "some_formname";
String qualificationString = "$1$ = \"" + entryId + "\"";
int firstRetrieve = 0;
int max_Retrieve = 0;
List sort_list = null;
boolean UseLocale = false;
OutputInteger nmatches = null;
ARServerUser=context    
Myentries = context.getListEntryObjects(formName, qualification, firstRetrieve, max_Retrieve , sort_list, fieldIds, UseLocale, nmatches);
```

This returns 0 entries. I suspect if its due to the `max_Retrieve` and `sort_list`. I don't know the total or maximum entries present. Please provide any inputs on why this is returning 0 entries, and how can I get the required entries from this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a 0, pass `Constants.AR_NO_MAX_LIST_RETRIEVE`